Dotnet app can not connect to mysql inside docker, but mysql is available outside docker
I have a simple dotnet app fresh template using mysql as database.
I tried adding docker on my project but for some reason im getting this error inside my dotnet container:
Error:
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.)
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

but when I try to connect mysql using tableplus (DBMS) its working fine.

heres my connection string:
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=lgu_hr;Uid=development;Pwd=development;"
heres my Dockerfile: (this is generated by rider IDE)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:9.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 5132

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:9.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LGU-HR-Web/LGU-HR.csproj", "LGU-HR-Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LGU-HR-Web/LGU-HR.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/LGU-HR-Web"
RUN dotnet build "LGU-HR.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "LGU-HR.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LGU-HR.dll"]


Heres my compose.yml
name: LGU_HR_APP

services:
  lgu-hr:
    image: lgu-hr
    container_name: lgu_hr_app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: LGU-HR-Web/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5132:5132"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app_network

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: lgu_hr_app_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: development
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: development
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: lgu_hr
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    

volumes:
  data:
    
networks:
  app_network:

I tried changing server connectionString localhost, 127.0.0.1, db, host.docker.internal, 172.18.0.1 (this is from mysql container Gateway)
Also when inspecting inside mysql container that I can confirm development@localhost is present.
I also tried going inside the dotnet app container and running .dll and confirm that it cant connect to mysql.
I also opened page 2 of google and still got no answer.
any suggestion would be great Christmas gift.
UPDATE
When I use this hostname 172.18.0.1 I get Connect Timeout expired error
UPDATE 2
I dont think this is the issue of health check for mysql or the app starting before the database because I tried running the database first and doing a exec command inside the app container and manually running it.
Anyway I figure it out but i dont know why i dont have explanation.
What you need to do is. add the connection string in the compose file environment and make sure the Server value will the database service name, in my case its db like:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=db;Port=3306;Database=lgu_hr;Uid=development;Pwd=development;

I dont have explanation as to why you have to name or assign value to Server as db and not localhost.
